# setField to a repeating group

Tags: c++, quickfix

In quickfix (C++ lib), we have:

```
class Group : public FieldMap
```

I call setField() to add a member to a repeating group (for example Parties) and in theory the call could throw exception of RepeatedTag. How to interpret this exception? Or for a Group object, it will never throw RepeatedTag?

The document (http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/repeating_groups.html) seems not worrying about this situation neither.

Answer (score 0):

It won't throw a RepeatedTagException.  (Where did you get that idea?)

RepeatedTagException is only thrown when the engine is reading an incoming message.

Comment: ```class FieldMap
{

Comment: ``` class FieldMap
{
 // I removed some here...
  ......
  void setField( const FieldBase& field, bool overwrite = true )
  EXCEPT ( RepeatedTag )

  void setField( int tag, const std::string& value )
  EXCEPT ( RepeatedTag, NoTagValue )


}```

Comment: when I populate a FIX::Message including FIX::Group, I called setField().

Comment: hope to get further comment in new year.